# Importing table records from a .csv file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer, and I have to insert 10 records having 114 columns, but it generates an error.

I  directly importing the `.CSV` file. It generated an error  `Duplicate column error`. I am a beginner, so please help me find the solution.

Here are some screen shots:
[image: Message log screenshot]

Comment: Can you please post an extract of your csv file? It seems that it contains many occurrences of the column `dl_number`

Comment: Can you also explain exactly what steps you are going through to do the import - which menu commands, options etc. you're setting. And preferably include the CSV extract and sample log message as text, not images.

Comment: Sorry i can't share the .csv file . And i am  just following Right click on table name and choose import data then a wizard opened,asking to choose .csv file and then click on next  and there are only 6 columns , having the same  name that is DL_NUMBER . i selected and then finish and that is why i am getting such error msg. But why only 6 columns are there with the same name . My .CSV file Containing 114 columns.

Comment: and one more thing while importing my .csv file there i saw funny records like in the format of symbols while importing then in the preview.

Comment: can it be possible that my .csv file data format is in UNICODE and SQL developer using some different format something like that ..